# Typescript for website with one global file and individual page files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'll preface this by saying that I've never used Typescript before, I'm tentatively experimenting with it because I really like the idea of "stricter JS". However, my knowledge of it is extremely limited at this time.

I've basically built my own library of functions for my website. A "core.js" file that is built by concatenating the files in "core/*.js". Each of those files would define properties on a global `window.myLib` object.

Then, each page has its own JS file that handles events for that particular page. They can call things from the global `window.myLib`.

Each page then has two script files:

```
<script src="/core.js"></script>
<script src="/js/page_name_here.js"></script>
```

And this works quite nicely.

I'm using VSCode for development and have set up a "globals.d.ts" file that lists what properties and functions are defined in the library, which allows Intellisense to provide very useful tooltips and hints on what is where.

So I'm wanting to "level up" by actually going full Typescript with this, and having `tsc` compile my JS files.

Step 1 would be compiling the library. At the moment this is done PHP-side(!) by checking file modification times and, if necessary, concatenating the files and sending the result off to closure-compiler. I believe this is how I should do it in TS -- is this correct?

```
window.myLib = {}
window.myLib.eventHandlers = require("./core/event-handlers.ts")
window.myLib.AJAX = require("./core/ajax.ts")
// ...
```

If not, what is correct for building a file like this?

Step 2 then is the individual page files. I *think* since I've already done the work of defining "globals.d.ts" with the library functions, I don't have to do anything in particular to have those files be able to use library functions. `tsc` should be able to read the definitions and use them whenever I refer to `window.myLib`. Am I correct on that, or do I actually need to reference the core file in some way?

Any further pointers aside from these two questions would be much appreciated as well. I'm very eager to try something new (to me) but there's a bit of a massive leap between "just write the JS and the browser will figure it out" and "you're writing for a compiler now!"

Comment: `I believe this is how I should do it in TS -- is this correct?` not quite. We don't use `require` in typescript, we use `import`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: @Olian04 that's technically incorrect. TypeScript is aware of `require` under certain module formats. It's definitely not something that I would recommend opting for by default, but there are some NodeJS as well ESM <-> CommonJS/AMD interop scenarios where it is helpful. `import` vs `require` is really a JS consideration that TypeScript supports

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol there's a lot wrong with that code both in terms of practices but also there are improper paths being required. You should really start with some basic applications to get a feel for TypeScript

Comment: @AluanHaddad That's fair. I have the general idea but a lot to learn! I'm mostly trying to get it to "just work" for now, but perhaps it's for the best to just stick with "JS files with VSCode providing basic checks"...

Comment: Well, once you want to use modules (`import` or `require`) in a browser, you need a loader or bundler, so it gets more way more complicated. It is well worth the effort, but not if you are going to use globals like `window.x = require('x')` because such globalsndefeat and negate the advantages of modules

Comment: @AluanHaddad I see. I was mostly thinking that so that I could keep separate files and bundle them together. I'm also noticing I'll have issues with AJAX requests since I would need to define the type of every single request/response so that TS can know what to expect. It seems like TS may not be the best tool for this job after all, and I should just continue with what I'm doing.

Comment: TypeScript is just JavaScript. If you write properly, it will infer most of the types for you , and you can always turn off strict. Really the issues I see in your code have nothing to do with TypeScript, they are JavaScript modularity concerns. That said, it is probably a good idea to get familiar with modules in pure JavaScript first, but TypeScript is great for tooling.

Answer (score 1):

As for the 'TS ==> JS' compile step, I strongly suggest you take a look at what [babel](https://babeljs.io/) has to offer. It plays quite nicely with the TS compiler through its plugin architecture, and can be integrated in most (if not all) modern build tools like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

**Warning**: setting up a full webpack-with-babel-wih-typescript project can be very time-consuming and feel tedious. You might hit the point where you feel that things are getting overly complex, for you 'just' wanted to do a website in TypeScript.

Not sure if you are doing this more as a learning project (where the quality of the final output is not the main concern), or if you want to use TypeScript *and get real*. In the latter case, I suggest taking a look at one of the popular frontend frameworks. Even if you want to have a fully static site, they offer solutions to modularity, and offer a (more or less) out-of-the-box TypeScript experience.

You might want to take a look at:

- [NuxtJs](https://nuxtjs.org/), which is based on the (somewhat easier-to-lean-than-react) [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) and [also supports TypeScript](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/)
- [Gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/), the [react](https://reactjs.org/)-equivalent to nuxtjs. I have [created a starter](https://github.com/stefanpl/gatsby-starter-nvon) with TypeScript, eslint+prettier, and a decent vscode config.
- [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), which [claims to love TypeScript](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript) and has gained enough hype to be taken seriously. Probably more fun than learning react, but not as mature.
- any of the other popular web frameworks that support TS. There are plenty. Just probably don't code something yourself, if you care about your hours-to-output ratio.

Each of those frameworks handles modularity slightly different, but for me it all boils down to:

- write small, modular functions with no implicit dependencies (e.g. don't depend on functions living on the `window` object!) and a single responsibility.
- import the functions (using [TypeScripts import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)) wherever you need them in your components
- let the framework do the rest, e.g. compiling, bundling, code splitting … the hard stuff

**TL;DR:** if you want to work on a (potentially) real project, use a framework.